# I have code like this:Dropdown button need to fetch the data which i have entered in input textfield

Tags: html, css

I have implemented autocomplete searchbar for my website.in that onclick of dropdown button input text field will appear,in the input text field i can enter my location.after entering my location my drop down should reflect the data which i have entered in input text field..but instead of that my drop down button is show again select location.
   
        
         Set Location

```
            <input type="search" class="form-control" id='locName' placeholder="Search Location" style=margin-top:-60px>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
<!--JavaScript Part-->
<!--AutoComplete Search bar-->
$(function() {
    $("#locName").autocomplete({
        source: [
            "Adugodi",
            "Arekere",
            "Attiguppe",
            "Yelahanka"

        ],
        minLength: 1,
        function(event) {
            var value = event.getAttribute('value')
            var locName = document.getElementById("locName").value;
            if (value.includes('&')) {
                value = value.replace("&", "%26");
            }
            if (locName == "") {
                alert("Please Select your Location");
            } else {
                window.location = "http://www.example.com";
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Explain the problem better and add some example of the problem. Also when using `style=` in HTML element, wrap the content in `' '` or `" "`. For example `style='color: red;'` or `style="color: red;"`.

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) and [edit] your question. Use all the debugging tools and validators available to you and post a well-formatted, well-indented, [mcve]. Several parts of your code are either missing or just syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution in this case would be removing the outline and border from the :active and :focus of your div as follows:

```
.btn:focus, .btn:active {
  border: 0;
  transition: none;
  border-style: none;
  outline: none;
}
```